# Change all links http to https with search-and-repace-tool?

Tags: http, ee6

In my database there are old `http://`-urls (in different fields). I want to replace them all with `https://`

Does this work with the search-and-repace-tool (in EE6: Tools -> Data Operations -> Search and Replace ) without crashing the whole thing?

Also I am not sure how I could target the whole database. As you can see in my screenshot I had to choose a special channel field, but I want run the replace over alle fields.

Thanks in advance!
[image: Screenshot: Intended settings for search-and-repace-tool]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that with search & replace. The only "downside" is that you have to do it one custom field at a time. If you know what fields might have http:// in them you can skip the others.

Comment: Are you sure it will not kill my site with the settings I posted? I fear it could damage something 8-O

Comment: Absolutely positive, I use Search and replace a lot for various things. If in doubt create a copy of the site somewhere and test it out before comitting to the live site.

Comment: Ok, thanks, so I will try this!

Answer (score 1):

Are these links within your site? If yes, It might be easier to just setup a http to https redirect using htaccess or nginx config.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to satisfy Google & Co that don't like http-links.

Comment: The redirect happens at the server level, so google will only ever see https

Comment: But when Google crawls the site it sees http-links and interprets them as »unsecure links« - doesn't he?! Or am I wrong with this?!

Comment: Google sees the site after the redirects happen if you configure it at the server level. Wha type of server are you using, I can share what I use in my htaccess file for http to https redirecting.

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe that's correct, but I am not 100% sure. Is there any other opinion to this topic?

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider moving to relative links instead of hard-coding http: or https:. e.g., instead of:

```
<a href="https://www.mysite.com/page>Page</a>
```

You'd have:

```
<a href="/page">Page<a/>
```

That would obey the protocol your user is on and be flexible in case you ever change the domain. You'd find "https://www.mysite.com/" and replace it with "/".

On top of that, I'd set up your web server to forward http traffic to https. e.g., in Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.mysite.com
  Redirect 301 / https://www.mysite.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.mysite.com
  #rest of settings
</VirtualHost>
```

That would solve your http traffic problem. Google would index your site properly (https).

Comment: Thanks - but my problems are external links. Internal everything is https already.